# Disabling validations when reseting passwords in Devise/Warden

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, devise

I have a user model as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :invitable, 
    :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, 
    :token_authenticatable, :omniauthable

  validates_presence_of :nickname, :unless => :skip_nickname_requirement
end
```

I have a number of user records in the database with a nil nickname - those individuals were imported from another system and I don't actually have their nickname. Those users are invited to set their passwords via the lost passwords link like `http://example.com/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=iAYeQRwWrt8geC8eEXR4`, and then when they log in, add their personal details such as nickname, etc.

The problem is that when you go to that reset password you're prompted to enter your password (and again for confirmation). When you submit, validation fails because the nickname is nil.

**How do I disable the nickname validation when reseting your password?** I don't want to add the nickname textfield on the password reset form.

Thanks in advance for your thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if simple `validates_presence_of :nickname, allow_blank: true` would solve your problem, because you may want it to be blank only for those imported users. Therefore, other way would be to use custom validations.

```
# app/models/user.rb

class NicknameValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    record.errors[attribute] << "validation failed" unless :skip_nickname_requirement?(value)
  end

  private

  def skip_nickname_requirement?(values)
    # imported_from_legacy_system? would need to be implemented
    value.present? || self.imported_from_legacy_system?
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :invitable, 
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, 
     :token_authenticatable, :omniauthable

  validates :nickname, :nickname => true
end
```